# why I cant run this why this c++ code giving errors in visual studio ,though it is running well in code blocks after deleting #include "stdafx.h"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, codeblocks

why this c++ code is giving error in visual studio though it runs well in code blocks after deleting #include "stdafx.h"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void chintumal();

int main() {

    chintumal();
    return 0;
}

void chintumal() {

    cout << "this is anurag pradhan ! \n";
}
```

[screenshot of visual studio with entered code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0kkT.png)

Comment: Copy the text of the error message and paste it into the question.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2005 _main already defined in ConsoleApplication1.obj ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\Anurag Pradhan\Desktop\cpp project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Source.obj 1

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2005 _main already defined in ConsoleApplication1.obj ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\Anurag Pradhan\Desktop\cpp project\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Source2.obj 1

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\Anurag Pradhan\Desktop\cpp project\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe 1

Comment: or just check embedded screenshot

Comment: *In the question*, not as comments. Press "edit" and edit.

Comment: No, _into the question_, and _not as a screenshot_.

Answer (score 2):

You can have only one `main` function in your code. Looks like you have another `main` defined in `ConsoleApplication1.cpp` file.

Comment: Thank you very much !
Actually I'm a beginner hence facing little issues ,actually i made a project in visual studio and in the same project created two files with one one main function in each, hence my code was not running !

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm a beginner hence facing little issues ,actually i made a project in visual studio and in the same project created two files with one one main function in each, hence my code was not running !

Comment: You should always provide your comments under the answer. Now, can you delete this and post it as a comment. Good Luck

Comment: @TheApache: No, it is appropriate to post the answer as an, er, answer. The OP did the right thing here.